# Why is string not being written into tempfile?

Tags: python, list, with-statement, temporary-files, txt

I have a script where I create a tempfile and try to write a string onto it and then try to run a for loop within it (while the "with" method is "active").

In the for loop, I try to append specific lines according to a pre-defined pattern, but when I print the lists after appending the lines, not only do the lsist come out empty, but the division_text string was not registered in the temp file to begin with.

**I'm basically writing the string onto the temp file and reading it at the same time. Maybe this is the issue.**

The 3 prints at the end (one for each list) come out empty, consequently.

Why is the string not being printed into the temp file?

```
import tempfile    

division_text = 'Hello, world.'
my_list = []

keywords = ['Hello']
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(keywords))

# create temporary .txt file to store string output from web scrape (division_text)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write(bytes(division_text, encoding='utf8')) # division_text is a string variable with many lines of text

    for line in tmp:
        print(line)    
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            my_list.append(line)

print(len(token_amount)) # []
```

If I use `tmp.writelines()` instead, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

If I use `NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w')` instead, and use tmp.write(division_text), it gives me the following error: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`.

I get the same error when trying:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'r+') as tmp:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write(division_text)
    tmp.seek(0)
    tmp.read()
```

Comment: have you tried `tmp.write(division_text.encode('utf8'))` ? and fix your indentation

Comment: are you sure that `division_text` is a string?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have tried that and it says: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes. And yeah division_text is a string.

Comment: I just tried with NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'w') and then, tmp.write(division_text) and it says: io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: `tmp` is a file, and you need to rewind it via a `seek(0)` before attempting to read lines from it (or close and reopen it for reading).

Comment: creating a [mcve] from your code shouldn't be a problem for you. Do that, you'll get your fix

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there you go. Let me know if you need me to make other edits. Also, I used `seek(0)` and `tmp.read()` as @marineau recommended, but it yielded another error, as you see on my edited code above.

Comment: I think it's time to [edit] your question to create a real [mcve] and remove the useless stuff. Describe your problem properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround just in case the `r+` mode causes issues (no issues here but it may be system dependent)

```
import tempfile,os
division_text = "12.0"
# create a temporary file, don't delete it when done
tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode = 'w',delete=False)
with tmp_file as tmp:
    print(tmp.name)
    tmp.write(division_text)
# reopen the file for reading
with open(tmp_file.name) as tmp:
    new_division_text=tmp.read()
# remove the file manually
os.remove(tmp_file.name)
# print result
print(new_division)
```

the idea is to create the temporary file but tell python not to delete it once closed. Then open it again for reading.

In that case, using simple text write and read modes works.

Comment: It is wirint the string int the tmp file now, but the issue is that it is printing each character as a line, so no full phrases come out, just a vertical wall of text.

Comment: you probably are using some strange way to print them. Problem is once again the fact that you lack a real [mcve]. My code snippet is a [mcve], paste it in a python IDE, run, voilà. Everyone can run it and check that it works

Comment: Gotcha, I'll work on it. However, you can see how I print it above: print(line). What Python is doing is it's recognizing each line as a character, instead of entire lines. An idea I had was toturn the string into a list and post the contects to the temp file, but I dont think I can write a list onto a tempfile.

Comment: did you use write or writelines to write the file?

Comment: I'm trying both. When I use writelines, I get this error `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`

Comment: Actually, I WAS getting that error. Now, I'm just gettin the same output with wrtie and writelines. One character per line.